# add formtastic-bootstrap styles to formtastic 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have an input that looks like this:

```
<%= f.input :email %>
```

The output I get from formtastic(v3.1.5) and rails(v4.2) looks like this.

```
<li class="email input required stringish" id="applicant_email_input">
  <label for="applicant_email" class="label">Email<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
  <input maxlength="255" id="applicant_email" type="email" value="davedave@gmail.com" name="applicant[email]">
</li>
```

What I really want is for formtastic to emit:

```
<div class="email input required stringish form-group" id="applicant_email_input">
  <label for="applicant_email" class=" control-label">Email<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
  <span class="form-wrapper">
    <input maxlength="255" id="applicant_email" type="email" value="davedave@gmail.com" name="applicant[email]" class="form-control">
  </span>
</div>
```

This is what this app emmitted with formtastic(v2.3.1) and formtastic-bootstrap(v3.0.0) and rails(v4.1).

I'd love to just include the gem for formtastic-bootstrap and get that old behavior back, but near as I can tell, formtastic-bootstrap dropped out around formtastic 3.

Now I have an app with a couple thousand calls to f.input, and I need to massage the output coming from formtastic. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: possible avenue: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hacked version of `formtastic` I have named [`boomtastic`](https://github.com/r-spell) which will do what you want.

(This actually includes all that you require except for the `form-wrapper`.  However, the `form-wrapper` seems to be an element of `bootstrap-formtastic` only and not part of `formtastic` or standard `bootstrap`.  If you really want to have the `<span class="form-wrapper">`, I think you can add this by editing `boomtastic/lib/formtastic/inputs/base/wrapping.rb`.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use formtastic's custom input? Also, these links might help: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic/helpers/input_helper.rb and https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/625.

Specifically, Justin French recommends that you monkey patch your app with an initializer in config/initializers/formtastic_patches.rb that would look something like this:

```
module Formtastic
module Inputs
module Base
module Wrapping
def input_wrapping(&block)
template.content_tag(:li,
[template.capture(&block), error_html, hint_html].join("\n").html_safe,
wrapper_html_options
)
end
end
end
end
end
```

And then switch the :li for a :div.

Answer (score 0):

What about a solution that uses jquery to change your form at page reload?

```
var ready = function () {
    var $input = $('#applicant_email');
    var input_html = $input.html();
    $input.html('<span class="form-wrapper">' + input_html + '</span>');
}

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
```

You need to tell me how you want to select those fields, because in your example you did not include the full html and any explanation of the real problem.

I also see that the other divs have some other classes, that can be done with some easy `jquery`

Otherwise you can edit that gem

Comment: I mean, I guess, but I feel like the whole point of formtastic is to generate forms on the server side. A client side rewriting agent seems like too many layers.

Comment: @DaveMorse did you read their github page? They do not include any info about how to do this, so If you want you can build it your self and then do a pull request so you can add your own functionality to `formtastic`

Comment: @DaveMorse if you want to have a div on your page you use `javascript` or `jquery` to add it, you don't build a logic in the `backend` server with `ruby` to add a div on your page.
`formtastict` it is just a way to help people build forms, like it was with the `ruby on rails form helpers`, but if you are hard core developer you just use a front end framwork and `ajax` to do this things. If you want to build a new functionality for `formtastic` and make a `pull` request could make sense

Comment: @DaveMorse otherwise an other intelligent option is using the **simple_form** gem that supports bootstrap https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#bootstrap